# Android App dev in XDK fails to show map after Publishing

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I developed an Android app in intel-XDK using Google Maps Android API key. This works fine in dev and testing on devices. I built the app with the same key in code, jarsigned with my keystore, zip aligned, and published at the Playstore.  The Map is NOT appearing in the Product. invalidkey or unauthorisedurl . I pasted the cert SHA1 in dev console for api key too. Googling here and elsewhere for a solution I am still unable to bring the Map on product in Playstore.  How should I create the correct key for production ?  especially in XDK. Anything missing  in my build settings ?